# Creating a div to contain navbar in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

This is my first time posting to stackoverflow and wasn't able to find a thread answering my question specifically so I'm hoping I'm not asking in the wrong place.

I'm looking to create a wordpress site, what I have envisioned to my understanding would be a a fixed background, and a navbar in a div container and float:right. I have used "Resonar" as my theme and "Full screen BG image" as a plugin to assist with the fixed background. However I'm stuck on the navbar.

I'm new to CSS and have a very basic HTML background.

Comment: mention your code that you try

Comment: Hi Nasser, I am writing to stack overflow as I am not sure of what code I need to use to place my navbar into a div container and float it.

Comment: WordPress navigation located in the `header.php` file in the theme folder you can find you header code there and customize it as you want, keep in mind that you should create a child theme for your theme but as the test you can just change` header.php `file in your theme folder

Comment: what is your theme that you use?

Comment: Hi Nasser, thank you - I will look for the header. I don't quite understand what a child theme is (this is my first time using wordpress) so I will have to do some research on how to create one. The theme I am using is "Resonar".

Comment: fine searching is very useful, and here a blog for Resonar child theme have a look on that I hope help you https://wordpresschildthemes.com/resonar-child-theme/

Comment: Thank you for that Nasser, that's very helpful. Would you happen to have an idea of what CSS code I would need to use on the navbar to place it into a div and float it right?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create your own css file. When you scroll down, to the navbar add some class like "sticky" or something like this and in your css file you can change the background and whatever you want

Comment: Hi allen, thanks for the comment. I'm quite new to css so I'm not sure how I'd go about creating my own css file. Could I implement a code to the header.php file where the navbar css appears to be located to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can you try adding in the following css in "Appearance => Theme Options => Custom CSS box."

```
#header-id ul.menu { float: right; }
```

Comment: I gave that ago, didn't change anything I'm afraid. :(